Is $\mathbb{R}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$?
I am trying to solve a question from my real analysis book.

Is this statement correct? For every pair x < y of real numbers, there is a real number z such that x < z < y

I was thinking that the statement would be correct if $\mathbb{R}$ were dense in $\mathbb{R}$. (Is that even a correct assumption?)
So that made me think. Is $\mathbb{R}$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$? I am very new to this concept, but I tried to modify a proof that shows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
Proof. Let $x,~y\in \mathbb{R}$ where $x < y$. Let $\displaystyle a = \frac{1}{2}\left( x+y \right)$.$$\frac{1}{2} \left( x + x\right) < \frac{1}{2}\left( x+y \right)<\frac{1}{2} \left( y + y\right)$$
$$\iff$$
$$x < a < y$$
$$\text{Q.E.D}$$
Does this prove that the original statement is true?

your proof is correct. try to prove an even broader statement: in a metric space $(X, d)$, a set $A\subset X$ is always dense in itself.

@Surb $\Bbb Z$ is indeed dense in itself. the definition of density (at least the one that I am familiar with) is: given a metric space $(X, d)$ and a set $B\subset X$, a set $A\subset B$ is called dense in B if for all $b \in B$ and $ \varepsilon >0$, there exists some $a\in A $ such that $d(a, b)<\varepsilon$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

@KorenParkhov You (and ultralegend5385) are maintaining the OP's confusion between https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set which is a weaker notion when both are comparable, i.e. in the case of an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology.

$\Bbb R$ is indeed dense in $\Bbb R$. If in a metric space a subset $A$ is dense, then clearly so is any subset $B\supseteq A$. So, if $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so is $\Bbb R$ since it contains $\Bbb Q$. However, the statement that you are using the denseness for, doesn't really follow.

A subset $A\subseteq X$ is dense in a metric space $X$ if for every point $x\in X$, there is a sequence of points $\{y_n\}_{n\ge0}$ that converges to $x$.

So, $\Bbb R$ being dense in $\Bbb R$ does not imply that for every two real numbers, there is a real number in the middle. That said, your proof works to show this, but it doesn't show that $\Bbb R$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. (That is even easier, though.)
Hope this helps. :)

Thanks a lot :) One more thing, the definition that you provided is unfamiliar to me. I've just started learning real analysis and the definition in my book is as follows:
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are ordered fields. Then $A$ is dense in $B$ if, for any $x,y\in B$ with $x < y$, there exists $a \in A$ such that $x < a < y$.
Is this definition incorrect? I have seen other definitions online that include "metric spaces" but I don't really know what they are. Converging sequences hasn't been touched on yet in the book, so I am assuming that is why the author chose this definition.

@gibbon: Oh I see. That definition works for ordered fields so it is okay. In that case, your argument works. The general idea is that in all fields, you cannot compare things for example, it is true that $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$, however since $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ is not an ordered field, you cannot prove it using your definition so you need a more general definition.

@gibbon: And the idea for this other definition is that, for any point $x$ in $X$ and any given value $r>0$, if you can find a point $a\in A$ that has distance from $x$ less than $r$, then you say $A$ is dense in $X$. This is effectively what I have written. You can show that for ordered fields, this definition and your definition is the same. You should learn that at some point and probably revisit this answer.
